# Why isn't a global variable set immediately after defining a callback/listener function (asynchronous messaging, port.on)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am very new to writing Firefox add-ons. But, I am trying my best. So, I have this code, which I [got from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Run_scripts_in_a_tab):

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScript: 'self.port.emit("html", document.body.innerHTML);'
  });
  worker.port.on("html", function(message) {
   console.log(message)
  })
});
```

When I change it to:

```
var contentHtml = '';

var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScript: 'self.port.emit("html", document.body.innerHTML);'
  });
  worker.port.on("html", function(message) {
    contentHtml = message
  })
});

console.log(contentHtml);
```

It logs an empty string. Why is that?

What is the proper way of putting this into the variable `contentHtml`?

Comment: While the context of this question is using `port.on` in a Firefox add-on, it is effectively a duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more detailed discussion about asynchronous code in JavaScript see:

- [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

> It logs an empty string. Why is that?

Because you set `contentHtml = '';`. At the time that you `console.log(contentHtml);`, it has not changed.

> What is the proper way of putting this into the variable `contentHtml`?

The way you are doing it assigns it into `contentHtml` just fine.

Your issue is not functionally how to assign a value to `contentHtml`. It is not an issue specific to writing a Firefox add-on. Your issue is understanding the flow of asynchronous programming.

JavaScript tends to be written with unnamed functions defined inline where they are used. While this is more compact, I find that it tends to result in newer programmers not as readily understanding the execution flow of a program that is asynchronous.

I have re-written your code so it is more clear as to what happens when:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var contentHtml = '';

function workerAttachedToTabWhenTabActivated() {
    //This is executed every time a tab is activated.
    //It is not executed until that time.
    self.port.emit("html", document.body.innerHTML);
}

function receiveHtmlMessageFromWorkerViaPortOn(message) {
    //This is executed only when we receive a message via port.on that is named "html".
    //It is not executed until such a message is received.

    //We set contentHtml to message here. While the contentHtml variable is defined in the
    //  containing code, setting it here does not, currently, do us any good because
    //  the rest of the program has already completed by the time this is executed.
    contentHtml = message;

    //Show that we actualy do set contentHtml.
    console.log("contentHtml after receiving html message:" + contentHtml);
}

tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScript: 'workerAttachedToTabWhenTabActivated();'
  });
  worker.port.on("html", receiveHtmlMessageFromWorkerViaPortOn(message))
});

//When we execute the following statement contentHtml is still "".
//When we get here, we have set up our functions that are executed upon a tab becoming
//active, but that code has not yet been executed because no tab became active in the small
//amount of time between setting up those listeners and this executing.
console.log("contentHtml after setting up tab.attach:" + contentHtml);
```

As you should be able to see, setting the global variable `contentHtml` to the `message` does not do much good in this instance because execution has already passed the statement

```
console.log("contentHtml after setting up tab.attach:" + contentHtml);
```

by the time `contentHtml` is set to the `message`. Setting the global variable `contentHtml` to the `message` would only do some good if there were other asynchronous code which might execute later in which it was desired to know what the most recent `html` `message` that had been received was.

In general, everything that depends on the contents of the `html` `message` should be put in the function that is executed when that message is received.