# Firefox WebExtention won't load

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So, I tried to load my add-on using the `about:debugging` page in Firefox. But, it simply wouldn't load. Is there somewhere where an error would be logged that I could find it?

Here is my *manifest.JSON* code:

```
{
    "description": "Adds a stickfigure",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "StickMan",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/StickMan-48.png"
    },
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
          "id": "extention@stick.man",
          "strict_min_version": "45.0"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["StickManUpdate.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "icons/StickManButton.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Call StickMan",
    },
}
```

I hope that this helps other frustrated add-on creators.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look for errors in the Browser Console (shortcut: Ctrl-Shift-J)? We are going to need your *StickManUpdate.js* file. Potentially, also the icon files. However, I would not have expected those to cause a problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I took a look in the browser console, and the error was: `A promise chain failed to handle a rejection. Did you forget to '.catch', or did you forget to 'return'?
See https://developer.mozilla.org/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise

Date: Sun Jul 17 2016 11:17:52 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)
Full Message: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name at line 33 column 2 of the JSON data
Full Stack: readJSON/</<@resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:628:19
NetUtil_asyncFetch/<.onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:128:17`

Comment: here is the complete file tree: [https://github.com/the10thWiz/StickManExt](https://github.com/the10thWiz/StickManExt)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to your GitHub. However, whenever possible, all the code for a **complete**, **minimal** [mcve] **should be in the question**. In this case, it is certainly possible. Doing so has multiple benefits. Not the least of which is that you distilling your own code down to the **minimum** needed to demonstrate the issue can often help you resolve the issue yourself. It also helps in focusing other people on the exact problem you are having for this question, rather than having them solve most everything, like I did. Which is *really* answering 8, or so, different questions.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of loading issue is that you have multiple syntax errors in the [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) of your *manifest.json* file.  In your *manifest.json* file the lines at the end of the file:

```
        "default_title": "Call StickMan",
    },
}
```

Should not have the extra `,` (which would indicate you are going to have another property in the [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)):

```
        "default_title": "Call StickMan"
    }
}
```

If you were using the [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), the fact that you had these errors would have been obvious:

[image: FF dev edition WebExtension load error]

However, even if you are running Firefox 47.0.1 and had merely used the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>), as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386888/firefox-webextention-wont-load#comment64185809_38386888), you would have seen the error:

```
A promise chain failed to handle a rejection. Did you forget to '.catch', or did you forget to 'return'?
See https://developer.mozilla.org/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise

Date: Sun Jul 17 2016 11:11:22 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)
Full Message: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name at line 33 column 2 of the JSON data
Full Stack: readJSON/</<@resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:628:19
NetUtil_asyncFetch/<.onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:128:17
```

While a bit cryptic, it still shows the line number of the first issue:

```
Full Message: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name at line 33 column 2 of the JSON data
```

The error produced in the Browser Console of Firefox Developer Edition is a bit easier to parse as to what the issue is:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name at line 33 column 2 of the JSON data
Stack trace:
readJSON/</<@resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:859:19
NetUtil_asyncFetch/<.onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:128:17
```

**WebExtensions Development:**
The [WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) is currently in development. If you are developing a WebExtension, **you should be using either [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/), or [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) in order to test your code**.

## **More on your code:**

**Syntax error:**
In addition to the above syntax errors, you have more issues.  I did not attempt to resolve all of them, but did get sucked into fixing enough so that the add-on was functional.  The next reported error, a syntax error, is in your *StickManUpdate.js* file on the code:

```
browser.tabs.sendMessage(
    message: "End";
);
```

You have multiple issues here. Please see the [tabs.sendMessage() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage). You are missing the required `tabId` parameter. In addition, you appear to be mixing-up the difference between having an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) being passed as a parameter containing properties which are the information passed to the method versus a list of parameters which are other native types passed to a method. Note: It is not uncommon for there to be both a list of parameters of various native or non-native types and an Object containing properties which are data passed to the method.

**Assuming `browserAction` is defined:**
You use methods of `browserAction` in multiple locations where it should be `browser.browserAction`. `browserAction` by itself is not defined. Alternately, you could use `browserAction` as a shortcut by defining it like: `var browserAction = browser.browserAction;`.

**Use of [`browserAction.getTitle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/getTitle) as if it is synchronous when in reality it is asynchronous:**
You make a call to `browserAction.getTitle()` to get the value of the title. The value of the title is only available in the callback function, which you do not supply.  This implies a lack of understanding of asynchronous programming.  You might want to review some questions on that subject like:

- [Why isn't a global variable set immediately after defining a callback/listener function (asynchronous messaging, port.on)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132847/why-isnt-a-global-variable-set-immediately-after-defining-a-callback-listener-f/36142752#36142752)
- [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

**Wrong parameter type supplied to [`browserAction.setTitle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setTitle):**
This appears to, again, be confusion as to the difference between parameters of other native types and a parameter that is an Object (which may be an Object literal) which contains properties which are the information passed to the method. Admittedly, WebExtensions appear to almost arbitrarily mix using actual parameters and Objects with the properties functioning as parameters when passing information to methods. It appears that being careful as to which is being used in a particular method will be required.

**Not having various functions specify the ID for the tab:**
In multiple calls to various methods, you do not pass the `tabId` when you should. You are adding your `StickMan` `canvas` to a single tab per mouse click. You should be passing the tab ID for calls to multiple methods.

**Assigning to `document.body.innerHTML` in *stickman.js*:**
In general, assigning to [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) at any time should be avoided, if possible. It is a bad idea under most circumstances. In most instances, it may cause the entire DOM to be re-evaluated. For doing what you desire, adding HTML in text format to the DOM at the end of the HTML for an element, there is a specific function which is better/faster: [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).  Your code:

```
document.body.innerHTML+= '<canvas id="StickManCanvas0000000" width="100" height="200"></canvas>';
```

Could be written as:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<canvas id="StickManCanvas0000000" width="100" height="200"></canvas>');
```

However, it is still a bad idea to use `insertAdjacentHTML()` here. There is a significant stigma attached to using either `insertAdjacentHTML()` or assigning to `innerHTML`. Using either will result in your add-on receiving additional scrutiny when submitted to AMO for distribution. This is mostly because there are real security issues with using either methodology for changing the DOM.  The security issues are when what is being added is text that is dynamically generated from input/data which is not hard coded into your add-on. In addition, you are already mixing adding the element as text and performing changes to it using other JavaScript (e.g. assigning to `canvas.style.position`). You really should use one or the other.  In this case, it is better to construct `canvas` entirely in JavaScript. It is, after all, only 4 lines to do the same thing you were doing in the two you were using for the `innerHTML` assignment and the `getElementById()` to find the `canvas` element.

Personally, I like using `insertAdjacentHTML()` in many instances with complex structures. It is generally faster to use it for inserting larget amounts of HTML.  It also allows you to keep what is being inserted represented as text. Such text may be *much* easier to visualize the structure being added rather than figuring out what a large chunk of DOM generated using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) actually looks like. However, along with the other drawbacks mentioned above, using `insertAdjacentHTML()` may not lend itself as easily to writing modular code.

**Issues with how you insert you content script and `canvas`:**
Every time the user clicks on your browserAction button you insert another copy of your content script into the tab. This leads to issues of errors being generated due to the consumed content scripts getting the message sent by your call to `browser.tabs.sendMessage()` and not being able to find the `canvas`.  The correct solution to this is to only `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` the first time the button is clicked in a tab and then send a message to the content script each subsequent time the button is clicked in that tab causing the same `canvas` to be re-inserted into the DOM. An easy way to track if you have already loaded the StickMan into a particular tab is to use `setTitle()` to have the title for your button be different after the first run in that tab.

**Other issues:**
Note: Your code structure in *stickman.js* is a bit convoluted. You might want to address this.

### All together

*manifest.json*:

```json
{
    "description": "Adds a stickfigure",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "StickMan",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/StickMan-48.png"
    },
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "extention@stick.man",
            "strict_min_version": "45.0"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["StickManUpdate.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "icons/StickManButton.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Call StickMan",
        "browser_style": true
    }
}
```

*StickManUpdate.js*:

```js
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    browser.browserAction.getTitle({tabId:tab.id},function(title){
        if(title  === 'Call StickMan') {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                file: "/content_scripts/stickman.js"
            });
            browser.browserAction.setTitle({title:'Recall StickMan',tabId:tab.id});
        } else if (title  === 'Call StickMan again') {
            browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,"Draw");
            browser.browserAction.setTitle({title:'Recall StickMan',tabId:tab.id});
        }else {
            browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,"End");
            browser.browserAction.setTitle({title:'Call StickMan again',tabId:tab.id});
        }
    });
});
```

*stickman.js*:

```js
var running = true;
//document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<canvas id="StickManCanvas0000000" width="100" height="200"></canvas>');
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("width",100);
canvas.setAttribute("height",200);
//var canvas = document.getElementById('StickManCanvas0000000');
canvas.style.position = 'fixed';
canvas.style.left = '0px';
canvas.style.top = (window.innerHeight-200)+'px';
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
canvas.style.border = '1px dashed red';

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var pos = {
    x:0,
    headX:50,
    headY:20,
    bodyX:50,
    bodyY:150,
    leftArmX:25,
    leftArmY:90,
    rightArmX:75,
    rightArmY:90,
    leftLegX:30,
    leftLegY:200,
    rightLegX:70,
    rightLegY:200,
};

var setPos = function(x, y) {
    canvas.style.left = x+'px';
    canvas.style.top = (window.innerHeight-y-200)+'px';
};

var drawMan = function(time) {
    setPos(pos.x, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pos.headX, pos.headY, 20, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.moveTo(pos.headX, pos.headY);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.bodyX, pos.bodyY);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.rightLegX, pos.rightLegY);
    ctx.moveTo(pos.bodyX, pos.bodyY);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.leftLegX, pos.leftLegY);
    ctx.moveTo((pos.bodyX+pos.headX)/2, ((pos.bodyY+pos.headY)/5)*2);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.rightArmX, pos.rightArmY);
    ctx.moveTo((pos.bodyX+pos.headX)/2, ((pos.bodyY+pos.headY)/5)*2);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.leftArmX, pos.leftArmY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#888888';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pos.headX, pos.headY, 20, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    if(running) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(drawMan);
    }
};

drawMan();
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(m) {
    if(m === 'End' && running === true) {
        running = false;
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    } else if(m === 'Draw' && running === false) {
        running = true;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
});
```

Functionality demo [Note1: [You must navigate to an actual webpage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/executeScript). Note2: The tooltips that pop up to tell you what the title is of your browser_action button are not captured with the [program I used](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) to create the following *.gif*. Note3: I added the [`browser_style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action) property to the `browser_action` in your *manifest.json* file. It is new in Firefox 48. Without it, Firefox will issue a warning in the Browser Console when the add-on is loaded.]:

[image: StickMan Functionality demo]