# Can I save input data from popup.html in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on pretty simple extension. My popup.html has some radiobuttons, which represent set of predefined options for user. The problem is that logic of my content-script depends upon those options.

So, my question is:
**let us assume I would attach a script to 'popup.html' (meeting Chrome CSP) that listens to any change in my radiobuttons selection and as soon as it happens does someting like .localstorage.setItem(key, value)? Would my content-script be able to get this value from local storage at appropriate moment?**

Comment: Why couldn't you do that?

Comment: @Fralec I am very new to this. That's why I am asking. should I call `chrome.storage.localStorage.setItem()`?

Comment: You appear to be confused as to the difference between [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)  See: [window.localStorage vs chrome.storage.local](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279495/window-localstorage-vs-chrome-storage-local).  If interested, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39236352/3773011) has an example popup & options page which stores data to `chrome.storage.local` and it s tested and working in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally, you can do that. Here two examples:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
    message('Settings saved');
});

chrome.storage.local.get('value', function(obj) {
    //Notify that we get the value.
    message('Value is ' + obj.value);
});
```

Or you can use the sync storage:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
    message('Settings saved');
});

chrome.storage.sync.get('value', function(obj) {
    //Notify that we get the value.
    message('Value is ' + obj.value);
});
```

Here is [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

The difference between `chrome.storage` and `window.localStorage`, is that you can use `window.localStorage` on every recent browser. Also on websites. The stored objects will be stored until the user close the browser.

You are building a Chrome extension, so I would recommend you to use the API that was make for that.

Comment: Given that the question is specifically about [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), you should address the differences between that API and [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: Once again. Just to makesure I got it right. I create a popup.html. Attach script for that one in a way `<script src='trackSelectionChanged.js"></script>`, so it is friendly to CSP. In that script I take new values and just do `chrome.storage.set....` and AFTER THAT my content-scripts are able to access saved values?

Comment: Yep, be just careful: `chrome.storage.LOCAL.set` pr `chrome.storage.SYNC.set`