# Chrome / Firefox extension - Content script not listening for messages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing an extension for both Chrome and Firefox, and I have come across a problem.

Basically, I am trying to get a content script to listen to messages using `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(...)`, however it doesn't seem to work.

I tested it by sending a message from the content script. The background script (`ml.js`) had a listener that worked fine, but the lsitener in the content script just didn't get the message.

You can view the code in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Druzion/30c94bf17d4ea3a9a5852e4598124419) (or below).

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Messaging Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["ml.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.google.co.uk/*"],
            "js": ["cs.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

`ml.js`:

```
// When receive message...
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    if (message.key) {
        console.log('ML: First message received')
        // Send another message
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            'foo': 'bar'
        })
    }
})
```

`cs.js`:

```
// Send message to ml.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    'key': 'value'
})
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    console.log('CS: Second message received')
})
```

When tested in Firefox (by loading the add-on at about:debugging and then visiting Google), `cs.js` sent the message, and `ml.js` logged the message to the console, however `cs.js` didn't log the message.

I'll appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting the content script to receive the message it sent? This does not happen.  A message sent by a script is not received by the same script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Using `runtime.sendMessage()` (messages *to* background scripts):

The `runtime.sendMessage()` ([Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)/[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage)) method is used to send messages to scripts that are running in the background context (background scripts, popup scripts, etc). Even when it is used to send messages from a script that is in the background context (e.g. to [communicate between a popup script and a background script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39236352/3773011)), it will be received by other currently listening background context scripts, but not the script that is sending it.

To quote the [Google Chrome `runtime.sendMessage()` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) (emphasis mine):

> If sending to your extension, the `runtime.onMessage` event will be fired in every frame of your extension (**except for the sender's frame**)...

### Sending a message to your content script (`tabs.sendMessage()`)

If you are wanting to send a message from your background script to your content script you should be using `tabs.sendMessage()` ([Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage)/[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage)). Alternately, you can use the `connect()` methods in `runtime` and `tabs`, which then provide you with a port ([Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port)/[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/Port)).

References:

- [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) (Chrome)
- [Communicating with background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts) (Firefox)

Comment: The sending of the message from the content script was just for demonstration purposes, but I see now that it was unclear (also I didn't know that you cannot receive a message you send from the same script). I have updated the question (and Gist) with new code demonstrating the same error. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Basically, even if the message is sent from `ml.js` using `runtime.sendMessage`, the content script will not receive it using `runtime.onMessage`.

Comment: @Druzion, That is the expected behavior. `runtime.sendMessage()` is for sending messages to scripts in the background script context (e.g. background scripts popup scripts, etc.), not content scripts. If you want to send a message to your content script, you should use `tabs.sendMessage()`. Please see the documentation linked in the the "References" above.

Comment: @Druzion, No problem. I'm glad I was able to help.  In re-reading the Firefox `runtime.sendMessage()` documentation, I see that it could be a bit more clear. I've added it to my list of pages which I should update.

Comment: Yes, I was reading `runtime.sendMessage` as the method to send messages *to* content scripts, instead of from them.